# Excel function pointing to time column failed in some cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

As shown in the screenshot below, the function fails in some cells. The second screenshot shows that the failed cell was formatted as time. [image]

[image]

Comment: You have a check for <= 20:59:59, and then one for >= 22:00:00. Think that last one should be >= 21:00:00 (ie 9pm).

Comment: BTW, Your screenshot of your formula and data is virtually useless for doing proper troubleshooting. It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet.  Much better to post this as text.

Comment: Hmmm. I still don't understand you point. @RonRosenfeld

Comment: My point is that you cannot transfer your screenshot to a worksheet. Do you have some special program that allows pasting a screenshot into a worksheet and using the results as data and formulas?

Answer (score 1):

You have a complicated `IF` statement that is difficult to debug so you are not seeing the obvious error (a missing time period).

Usually, when you have long and complicated IF statements, there is a better way of accomplishing what you want.

In this case, I would suggest using a lookup **Table** and the `VLOOKUP` function.

I Named the table `BELTS` and used this simpler formula:

```
    =VLOOKUP(HOUR([@TIME]),Belts,2)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice one I will look into this. Thanks. But, I am still unable to solve that problem.

Comment: @Powersurge what problem can't you solve? As you can see, this formula appears to provide the desired results.

Comment: Yes. It did. I am just pondering on the reason why that formula didn't work, moving forward

Comment: @Powersurge as I wrote, you are missing a time period in your lengthy `IF` statement.

Comment: Thank you! The Vlookup function is way better.